# Insert padding in body with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I try to insert in css file, an padding with jQuery. I want to do this, because i implemented an counterdown, and when it's active it's necessary to add in body an padding-bottom:189px.

How can i do that?

Thanks for help and time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document.body).css('padding-bottom', '189px');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! :) But...this operation it's necessary when my timer is active. The timer is https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/uji-countdown/ .

Comment: Than you need to call this bit of code when your timer changes. Something like: $('#timer').change(function() { `insert code here` }

Answer (score 2):

`$('body').css('padding-bottom', '189px');` will work as you want. However, it's **generally** preferred for separating dynamic JavaScript behaviour from presentational styles to add a class instead through `$('body').addClass('body--padding');` where

```
.body--padding{
  padding-bottom: 189px
}
```

There's also a small performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

A counter with jquery? I dont understand why people need apis for that. You can simply do:

```
document.all.body.style.paddingBottom="189px";
```

Comment: I never calculated it, but i think doing a small countdown in js is much smaller in size than including the whole jquery stuff. And people should learn proper js first before they get into jquery

Comment: A countdown might not be the only thing on the page.

Comment: The counter is implemented in wordpress site. It's a plugin for wordpress : https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/uji-countdown/ . Thanks for reply!